# Discussion about the use of 'what'

Tags: what, what-that

A friend of mine wrote me this:

> I understand everything (what) you write.

I mentioned that it was probably better to write '**that**' *instead of* 'what´. We were not able to find the correct answer, partly because it is not our mother tongue.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi Gerda, you may not be aware that this EL&U site is for "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts", whereas your question is probably more suited to our other site [ell.se]. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: Please do not close: edit. There is a really good question here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of "what" vs "that"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107073/use-of-what-vs-that)

Comment: @shoover puhlease. The answers there are inadequate; Colin Fine's answer here should be the archival answer.

Comment: 'Everything what you right' sounds like Estuary English (that is, it is not standard English, but in some dialects it is how you say it).

Answer (score 3):

*What* can be used as a [fused relative pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun#Antecedents) - the equivalent of "that which". So "I understand what you write" is grammatical and idiomatic.

You are trying to use it as a relative pronoun or subordinator, qualifying *everything*. This is common in some varieties of English, but not (as far as I know) in any standard varieties. So "I understand everything what you wrote" is not grammatical in standard English. (For a well-known example of this non-standard usage, see [*The Play What I Wrote*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Play_What_I_Wrote), a play about comedy double acts. The title is a catch phrase that the duo Morcambe and Wise used in their show, which was deliberately non-standard for comic effect. )

So you need to follow "everything" with either a separate relative pronoun ("which") or a subordinator ("that") - or nothing, because where the relative pronoun is not the subject of the relative clause, you can omit it.

I would say these are in reverse order of naturalness, so the most natural form in speech is

> I understand everything you write.

The next most common, and slightly more formal, is

> I understand everything that you write.

The third possibility, while grammatical, is less usual:

> I understand everything which you write.

(You may find people who say that you can't use "which" in a restrictive relative clause. They are wrong. Oliver Kamm says in *Accidence Will Happen*: "One thing you won't find in style guides that advocate the *that/which* rule is the slightest substantiation for it").

Comment: I had a discussion about this here on ELU a few years back (I'll see if I can find it, but I don't think there's a way to search in comments), where somebody persuaded me with some difficulty that _that_ is not a relative pronoun, but a subordinator that in many contexts can replace a relative pronoun.

Comment: [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257508/why-is-it-impossible-to-put-a-preposition-in-front-of-the-relative-that) is a thread where I referred to the previous discussion!

Comment: The comments [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222133/the-usage-of-that-as-a-relative-pronoun) indicate that this analysis is to be found in CGEL. I wish I could find the comment thread here where somebody convinced me.

Comment: There's plenty of evidence to support the claim that "that" is a subordinator, not a relative pronoun. For instance, "the patients to whom the letter was sent" is grammatical but *"the patients to that the letter was sent" is of course not. If "that" were a relative pronoun, the latter would be grammatical.

Comment: Found it, @KannE! My conversation with Aaron in the comments to my answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17143/can-who-as-a-relative-pronoun-sometimes-be-omitted/17207#17207)